# matlab: vectorizing a single loop that is ORing N binary matrices

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, vectorization

The below code do some computation on a `data` matrix, the data is laid as --

```
data = [ ...
        1 2 3 4 5 6; ...
        1 2 3 4 5 6; ...
        1 2 3 4 5 6;]
```

and the code that I am running is like this --

```
[~,col] = size(data) ;
flag1 = bsxfun(@lt, data(:,1), data(:,1).'); 
flag2 = bsxfun(@gt, data(:,1), data(:,1).'); 

for cindex = 2:col % can we get rid of this loop ?
    flag1 = flag1 | bsxfun(@lt, data(:,cindex), data(:,cindex).');
    flag2 = flag2 | bsxfun(@gt, data(:,cindex), data(:,cindex).');
end
```

what this code is doing is comparing each row in column major order and creating two matrices of binary values `flag1` and `flag2`.

Is there anyway to get rid of this `for cindex = 2:col` loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some [`permuting(rearrange dimensions)`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to create `singleton dimensions` so that expansions would take place when using `bsxfun` later on, which would essentially replace the looping as used in the original posted code. So, the implementation would look something like this -

```
flag1 = any(bsxfun(@lt,permute(data,[1 3 2]),permute(data,[3 1 2])),3);
flag2 = any(bsxfun(@gt,permute(data,[1 3 2]),permute(data,[3 1 2])),3);
```

Comment: I knew you can do it!!

Answer (score 1):

I was curious to see, how much gain I am actually getting, it's actually a double speedup! here is a benchmark --

```
clear all 

data = rand(500,500);
[~,col] = size(data);
maxrun = 20 ;

%warm up
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

toctime = 0 ;
for i = 1:maxrun
    flag1 = bsxfun(@lt, data(:,1), data(:,1).'); 
    flag2 = bsxfun(@gt, data(:,1), data(:,1).'); 
    tic
    for cindex = 2:col % can we get rid of this loop ?
        flag1 = flag1 | bsxfun(@lt, data(:,cindex), data(:,cindex).');
        flag2 = flag2 | bsxfun(@gt, data(:,cindex), data(:,cindex).');
    end
    toctime = toctime + toc ;
end
fprintf('time elapsed: %0.4f sec\n', toctime/maxrun);

toctime = 0 ;
for i = 1:maxrun
    flag1 = bsxfun(@lt, data(:,1), data(:,1).'); 
    flag2 = bsxfun(@gt, data(:,1), data(:,1).'); 
    tic
    for cindex = 2:col % can we get rid of this loop ?
        flag1 = bsxfun(@or, flag1, bsxfun(@lt, data(:,cindex), data(:,cindex).'));
        flag2 = bsxfun(@or, flag2, bsxfun(@gt, data(:,cindex), data(:,cindex).'));
    end
    toctime = toctime + toc ;
end
fprintf('time elapsed: %0.4f sec\n', toctime/maxrun);

toctime = 0 ;
for i = 1:maxrun
    tic
    flag1 = any(bsxfun(@lt,permute(data,[1 3 2]),permute(data,[3 1 2])),3);
    flag2 = any(bsxfun(@gt,permute(data,[1 3 2]),permute(data,[3 1 2])),3);
    toctime = toctime + toc ;
end
fprintf('time elapsed: %0.4f sec\n', toctime/maxrun);

fprintf('done.\n');
```

one interesting thing to note doing `|` over two matrices and doing `bsxfun(@or...` are almost same --

```
>> vectest
time elapsed: 0.8609 sec
time elapsed: 0.7914 sec
time elapsed: 0.3285 sec
done.
```